# Not finding field after join

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with the InnoDB version of MySQL's *world* database (available [here](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/world_innodb.sql.gz)) and am trying to fetch a list of the countries of South America and their capitals. In my mind, the query should look like this:

```
    SELECT `Country.Name` as `CountryName`, `City.Name` as `CityName`
    FROM `Country`, `City` 
    WHERE `Continent` = 'South America' AND `ID` = `Capital`;
```

But that one gives error `#1054 - Unknown column 'Country.Name' in 'field list'`, even though the table `Country` does have the field `Name`.

Why isn't MySQL finding the fields I want? How do I change the query to make it find them?

Let me know if I need to provide more information for you to be able to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you quote identifiers, do not surround the inner dot with backticks.

```
SELECT
  `Country`.`Name` AS CountryName,
  `City`.`Name` AS CityName
```

If you quote around the inner dot, it will be assumed to be inside the column name, rather than a separator between the table name and column name -- you have a column named `Name`, but not a *column* called `Country.Name`.  In this case, however, it is unnecessary to quote any of the identifiers since none of them are [MySQL reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html).

Comment: Try to avoid backticks unless you really need them. As @Michael pointed out, backticks are useful when identifiers clash with MySQL reserved keywords.

Comment: Thanks, it's working. An easy catch for a trained eye, I guess. I've read that backticks aren't necessary, but do I gain anything from avoiding them? I read somewhere that a guy ran into trouble during an upgrade because one of his non-backticked field names had become a reserved keyword in a later MySQL version.

Comment: @JohannaLindh You don't gain anything by avoiding them.  MySQL doesn't often add new reserved words, though.  If you get into the habit of always quoting, that's just fine.  I'm more apt to avoid using anything resembling a reserved word than quoting, myself.

Answer (score 2):

Try modifying your back ticks.

```
SELECT 
    `Country`.`Name` as `CountryName`,
    `City`.`Name` as `CityName` 
FROM `Country`, `City`
WHERE `Continent` = 'South America' AND `ID` = 'Capital';
```

Do not put them around the entire table.column, but around them individually with the period between them.

Also capitol should be single quotes and not back ticks.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a syntax issue:

Try using this instead:

```
`Country`.`Name`
```

country.name (in ticks) would be the name of the field when what your after is

```
`country`.`name`
```

Comment: Thank you! Beginner's mistake. :)